# How do I invoke a function within a for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, meteor, invoke

How can I call a within a for loop function?
As of now, the returned `singleObject` is coming out as `undefined`.

What I am trying to achieve is as follows.

1. create my object from each iteration
2. Pass this object into another function and process further. Do I 'return' the next function. I am confused as to how to invoke functions within a function in this for loop.

---

```
function createObjectFromArray(array) { // data is an array with multiple object
    var len = array.length
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        var singleObject = {
            fieldOne: array[i].someField.valueOne,
            fieldTwo: array[i].someField.valueTwo
        }
    } //end of for loop
    myNextFUnction(singleObject)
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Why don't you just call the function inside the for loop?

Comment: You aren't doing anything asynchronous, why would you use `.wait`?

Comment: @Quntas, you are correct, I don't need to use .wait

Comment: The reason why I would want the next function within the for loop is that each iteration creates an object. This object needs is being checked against my database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize singleObject before the loop. In your example its scope is the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you are calling `createObjectFromArray()` before some asynchronous method has returned the data array. Most likely `array` is empty or undefined as a result

You also have a problem within the function where your `singleObject` only gets defined if there is an array length. This is likely why you see it undefined in the next function

But on top of that your loop overwrites `singleObject` on every iteration so even when your data does exist you will only ever pass the last iteration of `singleObject` to `myNextFUnction` .

Please show where you are calling `createObjectFromArray()` for further assistance